# Create SHA256withRSA in two steps

Tags: java, hash, signature, digital

For educational purposes, I would like to be able to first create a Hash for a String and then to create RSA Digital Signature from that Hash so that the result is the same as when using SHA256withRSA in one go. This way I want to confirm that I fully understand all the steps that are actually being done automatically for us when we call SHA256withRSA.

I also have one additional question. Is Digital Signature done on Hash or on Base64 Encoded Hash?

Below is the code that I am currently using and here is the output of the code which shows that these two approaches produce different signatures which means that I am missing soma manual steps.

```
AUTOMATICALLY SIGN & VERIFY
SIGNATURE = Hj6a86sR2cJoQFolbxj0blk2I9CAdTdx6WOles5t/pyUyJwa9rp2/SRx2wyXWgc6GsvoZYGLUedeJ2Lklm5hYgT/TtNBATk5eChgfkJMz3NBIRPrsl7ZPG7Wvo4VmHsPpoZZ8PdRk8qY9RLou86OyIqRcX62isuV+e/0deHJ+yTZz4vqA3y+PE4yRFp96A8sKw5VlDnByn7bsxM/QOS+sQWTsETzU9s4YSRfKNq1Urn8/VDoel7n0ORjR918P+0kwE+G77bAOI70yQZorvmbgrMLSBJeVzkKzM/YECLWyrJsqdjfp86FkA9MPGB1V6rO8q8m5GhNoJOmNhC7Ek95Bw==

MANUALLY SIGN & VERIFY
HASH      = lDlahWCWx2b5TYUji52uPeReSW7vbro2wXuRsPKmOdA=
SIGNATURE = gsxw7UQpqni5HyPAw8wI2pvepbrDzizkOvO0hab1+7vi4EaYJi3n4lvnkBTOU5LXQKLZGzJcug0mL2pL/PVh8lrvzZ/F9CxULLxKpayrNkvL9yEWMvcfcku9Go5EGrxSzD7VYvkwOzHvGe4GgUGD1JOjvzXBAfJRT8h/wnZi9IPA9n31/tWI2eFw17Js/gymElycp7pjrpEhUNe/IVTP9HVfRQfAxEDAPW8GY/WFdxbD3Jk05LKvpTxua4jzCX9wJh/s8aiT9OvEXh3/zt06JSEpfgf+CpkOFJupmRhsgqebPfVQEo24ctw1DnipKkL771mm30bFcm/FF1reXuOqqQ==
```

---

```
public class Main {

  //====================================================================================
  // MAIN
  //====================================================================================
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    //CREATE DATA
    String            dataString = "Data to be encrypted";
    byte[]            dataBytes  = dataString.getBytes();

    //CREATE KEYS
    KeyPairGenerator  keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
                      keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
    KeyPair           keyPair    = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    PrivateKey        privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();

    //AUTOMATICALLY SIGN & VERIFY
    System.out.println("\nAUTOMATICALLY SIGN & VERIFY");
    byte[]  automaticSignatureBytes = AutomaticHash.sign  ("SHA256withRSA", privateKey, dataBytes);

    //MANUALLY SIGN & VERIFY
    System.out.println("\nMANUALLY SIGN & VERIFY");
    byte[]  manualHashBytes         = ManualHash.hash  ("SHA-256", dataBytes);
    byte[]  manualSignatureBytes    = ManualHash.sign  ("NONEwithRSA", privateKey, manualHashBytes);

  }

}
```

---

```
public class AutomaticHash {

  //====================================================================================
  // AUTOMATICALLY SIGN
  //====================================================================================
  public static byte[] sign(String algorithms, PrivateKey privateKey, byte[] dataBytes) throws Exception {

    //CREATE SIGNATURE (use Hash first)
    Signature         signature = Signature.getInstance(algorithms);
                      signature.initSign(privateKey);
                      signature.update(dataBytes);
    byte[]            signatureBytes = signature.sign();

    //ENCODE SIGNATURE
    byte[]            signatureEncodedBytes  = Base64.getEncoder().encode(signatureBytes);
    String            signatureEncodedString = new String(signatureEncodedBytes);

    //DISPLAY ENCODED SIGNATURE
    System.out.println("SIGNATURE = " + signatureEncodedString);

    //RETURN SIGNATURE
    return signatureBytes;

  }

}
```

---

```
public class ManualHash {

  //====================================================================================
  // MANUALLY HASH
  //====================================================================================
  public static byte[] hash(String algorithm, byte[] dataBytes) throws Exception {

    //CREATE HASH
    MessageDigest digest    = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
    byte[]        hashBytes = digest.digest(dataBytes);

    //ENCODE HASH
    byte[]        hashEncoded = Base64.getEncoder().encode(hashBytes);
    String        hashEncodedString = new String(hashEncoded);

    //DISPLAY ENCODED HASH
    System.out.println("HASH      = " + hashEncodedString);

    //RETURN HASH
    return hashBytes;

  }

  //====================================================================================
  // MANUALLY SIGN
  //====================================================================================
  public static byte[] sign(String algorithm, PrivateKey privateKey, byte[] hashBytes) throws Exception {

    //SIGN HASH
    Signature         signature = Signature.getInstance(algorithm);
                      signature.initSign(privateKey);
                      signature.update(hashBytes);
    byte[]            signatureBytes = signature.sign();

    //ENCODE SIGNATURE
    byte[]            signatureEncodedBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encode(signatureBytes);
    String            signatureEncodedString = new String(signatureEncodedBytes);

    //DISPLAY ENCODED HASH & SIGNATURE
    System.out.println("SIGNATURE = " + signatureEncodedString);

    //RETURN SIGNATURE
    return signatureBytes;

  }

}
```

Comment: The hash of the data is signed. What is your question regarding the code?

Comment: So I have to sign hashBytes and not hashEncoded? Which is what I am currently doing.

I have updated question. Output of the code shows that these two approaches produce different signatures which means that I am missing soma manual steps.

Comment: _So I have to sign hashBytes and not hashEncoded?_ Yes. Regarding the different results, please see my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`SHA256withRSA` and `NoneWithRSA` use PKCS#1 v1.5 padding, more precisely RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5. This is a deterministic padding, i.e. repeated signing with the same data will produce the same signature. Details can be found in [RFC8017, 8.2.](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#section-8.2)

This padding applies the DER encoding of the *DigestInfo* that results for SHA256 when the byte sequence *(0x)30 31 30 0d 06 09 60 86 48 01 65 03 04 02 01 05 00 04 20* is prepended to the hash.

So your manual code must be modified e.g. as follows:

```java
public static byte[] sign(String algorithm, PrivateKey privateKey, byte[] hashBytes) throws Exception {

    byte[] id = new byte[] { 0x30, 0x31, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x60, (byte) 0x86, 0x48, 0x01, 0x65, 0x03, 0x04, 0x02, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x04, 0x20 };
    byte[] derDigestInfo = new byte[id.length + hashBytes.length];
    System.arraycopy(id, 0, derDigestInfo, 0, id.length);
    System.arraycopy(hashBytes, 0, derDigestInfo, id.length, hashBytes.length);

    // SIGN HASH
    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(algorithm);
    signature.initSign(privateKey);
    signature.update(derDigestInfo);
    byte[] signatureBytes = signature.sign();

    ...
```

With this change, both `sign()` methods return the same result.

---

Btw, [`java.util.Base64.Encoder.encodeToString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#encodeToString(byte%5B%5D)) *directly* generates a Base64 encoded string.

In addition, when encoding/decoding, a charset should always be specified, e.g. `dataString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` or `new String(..., StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`. Otherwise the platform's default charset is used, which may differ from the intended one.

Comment: Can you also do it for SHA-1?

Comment: For SHA-1 it is analogous, just use the appropriate identifiers (`"SHA1withRSA"` and `"SHA-1"`) and the appropriate byte sequence (_(0x)30 21 30 09 06 05 2b 0e 03 02 1a 05 00 04 14_), see for the latter and other digests [RFC8017, p.47](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8017#page-47). Caution: SHA-1 is insecure!

Answer (score 5):

Here is a complete code based on Comments for SHA-1 and SHA-256

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;

public class Main {

  //====================================================================================
  // MAIN
  //====================================================================================
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    //CREATE DATA
    String            dataString = "Data to be encrypted";
    byte[]            dataBytes  = dataString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    //CREATE KEYS
    KeyPairGenerator  keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
                      keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
    KeyPair           keyPair    = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
    PrivateKey        privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate();
    PublicKey         publicKey  = keyPair.getPublic();

    //SIGN
    SHA1withRSA  (privateKey, publicKey, dataBytes);
    SHA256withRSA(privateKey, publicKey, dataBytes);

  }

  //====================================================================================
  // SHA1 WITH RSA
  //====================================================================================
  private static void SHA1withRSA(PrivateKey privateKey, PublicKey publicKey, byte[] dataBytes) throws Exception {

    //LOG
    System.out.println("\nSHA1 WITH RSA ==================================================================");

    //AUTOMATICALLY SIGN & VERIFY
    System.out.println("\nAUTOMATICALLY SIGN & VERIFY");
    byte[]  automaticSignatureBytes = AutomaticHash.sign  ("SHA1withRSA", privateKey, dataBytes);
    Boolean automaticVerified       = AutomaticHash.verify("SHA1withRSA", publicKey , dataBytes, automaticSignatureBytes);

    //MANUALLY SIGN & VERIFY
    System.out.println("\nMANUALLY SIGN & VERIFY");
    byte[]  manualHashBytes         = ManualHash.hash   ("SHA-1", dataBytes);
    byte[]  manualPaddingHashBytes  = ManualHash.padding("SHA-1", manualHashBytes);
    byte[]  manualSignatureBytes    = ManualHash.sign   ("NONEwithRSA", privateKey, manualPaddingHashBytes);
    Boolean manualVerified          = ManualHash.verify ("NONEwithRSA", publicKey , manualPaddingHashBytes, manualSignatureBytes);

  }

  //====================================================================================
  // SHA256 WITH RSA
  //====================================================================================
  private static void SHA256withRSA(PrivateKey privateKey, PublicKey publicKey, byte[] dataBytes) throws Exception {

    //LOG
    System.out.println("\nSHA256 WITH RSA ================================================================");

    //AUTOMATICALLY SIGN & VERIFY
    System.out.println("\nAUTOMATICALLY SIGN & VERIFY");
    byte[]  automaticSignatureBytes = AutomaticHash.sign  ("SHA256withRSA", privateKey, dataBytes);
    Boolean automaticVerified       = AutomaticHash.verify("SHA256withRSA", publicKey , dataBytes, automaticSignatureBytes);

    //MANUALLY SIGN & VERIFY
    System.out.println("\nMANUALLY SIGN & VERIFY");
    byte[]  manualHashBytes         = ManualHash.hash   ("SHA-256", dataBytes);
    byte[]  manualPaddingHashBytes  = ManualHash.padding("SHA-256", manualHashBytes);
    byte[]  manualSignatureBytes    = ManualHash.sign   ("NONEwithRSA", privateKey, manualPaddingHashBytes);
    Boolean manualVerified          = ManualHash.verify ("NONEwithRSA", publicKey , manualPaddingHashBytes, manualSignatureBytes);

  }

}
```

---

```
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.util.Base64;

public class AutomaticHash {

  //====================================================================================
  // AUTOMATICALLY SIGN
  //====================================================================================
  public static byte[] sign(String algorithms, PrivateKey privateKey, byte[] dataBytes) throws Exception {

    //CREATE SIGNATURE (use Hash first)
    Signature         signature = Signature.getInstance(algorithms);
                      signature.initSign(privateKey);
                      signature.update(dataBytes);
    byte[]            signatureBytes = signature.sign();

    //DISPLAY ENCODED SIGNATURE
    System.out.println("SIGNATURE = " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signatureBytes));

    //RETURN SIGNATURE
    return signatureBytes;

  }

  //====================================================================================
  // AUTOMATICALLY VERIFY
  //====================================================================================
  public static Boolean verify(String algorithms, PublicKey publicKey, byte[] dataBytes, byte[] signatureBytes) throws Exception {

    //INITIALIZE SIGNATURE
    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(algorithms);
              signature.initVerify(publicKey);
              signature.update(dataBytes);

    //VERIFY SIGNATURE
    boolean   verified = signature.verify(signatureBytes);

    //DISPLAY VERIFICATION
    System.out.println("VERIFIED  = " + verified);

    //RETURN SIGNATURE
    return verified;

  }

}
```

---

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Signature;
import java.util.Base64;

public class ManualHash {

  //====================================================================================
  // HASH
  //====================================================================================
  public static byte[] hash(String algorithm, byte[] dataBytes) throws Exception {

    //CREATE HASH
    MessageDigest digest    = MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
    byte[]        hashBytes = digest.digest(dataBytes);

    //DISPLAY ENCODED HASH
    System.out.println("HASH      = " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(hashBytes));

    //RETURN HASH
    return hashBytes;

  }

  //====================================================================================
  // PADDING
  //====================================================================================
  public static byte[] padding(String algorithm, byte[] hashBytes) throws Exception {

    //PREPARE PADDING
    byte[] padding = null;
    if (algorithm.equals("SHA-1"  )) { padding = new byte[] { 0x30, 0x21, 0x30, 0x09, 0x06, 0x05, 0x2b, (byte) 0x0e, 0x03, 0x02, 0x1a, 0x05, 0x00, 0x04, 0x14                         }; }
    if (algorithm.equals("SHA-256")) { padding = new byte[] { 0x30, 0x31, 0x30, 0x0d, 0x06, 0x09, 0x60, (byte) 0x86, 0x48, 0x01, 0x65, 0x03, 0x04, 0x02, 0x01, 0x05, 0x00, 0x04, 0x20 }; }

    //ADD PADDING & HASH TO RESULTING ARRAY
    byte[] paddingHash = new byte[padding.length + hashBytes.length];
    System.arraycopy(padding  , 0, paddingHash, 0             , padding.length  );
    System.arraycopy(hashBytes, 0, paddingHash, padding.length, hashBytes.length);

    //RETURN HASH
    return paddingHash;

  }

  //====================================================================================
  // SIGN
  //====================================================================================
  public static byte[] sign(String algorithm, PrivateKey privateKey, byte[] paddingHash) throws Exception {

    //SIGN PADDED HASH
    Signature         signature = Signature.getInstance(algorithm);
                      signature.initSign(privateKey);
                      signature.update(paddingHash);
    byte[]            signatureBytes = signature.sign();

    //DISPLAY ENCODED HASH & SIGNATURE
    System.out.println("SIGNATURE = " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(signatureBytes));

    //RETURN SIGNATURE
    return signatureBytes;

  }

  //====================================================================================
  // MANUALLY VERIFY
  //====================================================================================
  public static Boolean verify(String algorithm, PublicKey publicKey, byte[] hashBytes, byte[] signatureBytes) throws Exception {

    //INITIALIZE SIGNATURE
    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance(algorithm);
              signature.initVerify(publicKey);
              signature.update(hashBytes);

    //VERIFY SIGNATURE
    boolean   verified = signature.verify(signatureBytes);

    //DISPLAY VERIFICATION
    System.out.println("VERIFIED  = " + verified);

    //RETURN SIGNATURE
    return verified;

  }

}
```

---

Result

```
SHA1 WITH RSA ==================================================================

AUTOMATICALLY SIGN & VERIFY
SIGNATURE = bGLX8elMdZeyDmT1YCh86Uz5kH9P69NpAqYYNn11ybyYp2cqLUSyqTEolhv4QgEAnSoyGQH9McjEMqhDL+u8Kp68nDRmt2ScFtNN17i0F7+65XO2PHqQtpfOsb2tUoG4Q+SmoBWSiXJliIQTRjYeblgLteY74SJreDlN7AAEYmFpi9oVbptwCj0OnZMlz5EdffX66Yy47qxYSF3O3Wuea1mCY/lG52qHwTFFJ+//N+X/5wFX4UDpzA+BMoWynE7FKzzfkQOGl9LazhFCTH46i30UHXmNGlbrjpApRtZKL9LnZUNPbLJTVKtCDZFMEdocT/a9NBeclZPtu/LBj3l+Iw==
VERIFIED  = true

MANUALLY SIGN & VERIFY
HASH      = +AayjWUd2pEmeoC49PlJj2mMdG4=
SIGNATURE = bGLX8elMdZeyDmT1YCh86Uz5kH9P69NpAqYYNn11ybyYp2cqLUSyqTEolhv4QgEAnSoyGQH9McjEMqhDL+u8Kp68nDRmt2ScFtNN17i0F7+65XO2PHqQtpfOsb2tUoG4Q+SmoBWSiXJliIQTRjYeblgLteY74SJreDlN7AAEYmFpi9oVbptwCj0OnZMlz5EdffX66Yy47qxYSF3O3Wuea1mCY/lG52qHwTFFJ+//N+X/5wFX4UDpzA+BMoWynE7FKzzfkQOGl9LazhFCTH46i30UHXmNGlbrjpApRtZKL9LnZUNPbLJTVKtCDZFMEdocT/a9NBeclZPtu/LBj3l+Iw==
VERIFIED  = true

SHA256 WITH RSA ================================================================

AUTOMATICALLY SIGN & VERIFY
SIGNATURE = M7bqVsCdlQnjCBBupuOmCJSzhuZ4C2K1VsNcJUXpdKBt17jy3TbFKcaYQ47Lsj0x/xqHFK3OTFxxZRjZyywqk25ovyzTfCkwHoEYWE2TiApEkf92pTcVn86YkFhDQCSJWboJu75NAEtDxkiJelUut3DmHp0Pu91U17cKC6JxUSIHlTQAxbNHhUfkx0YdE6sTvzK2lG/XJcZdA/Nx6qia9548EsBoi71vY1GlsSn7pEf5pg5yCJF5fAufD9hRSPI5OX2TKtj3hYXMr8UXQ6VaDBf4PiJjQ8MNg+q4cXtr+BpK1uHtxm0BuRHlcM4eBkTyuia93Xc88Ojwsma2tlCrwg==
VERIFIED  = true

MANUALLY SIGN & VERIFY
HASH      = lDlahWCWx2b5TYUji52uPeReSW7vbro2wXuRsPKmOdA=
SIGNATURE = M7bqVsCdlQnjCBBupuOmCJSzhuZ4C2K1VsNcJUXpdKBt17jy3TbFKcaYQ47Lsj0x/xqHFK3OTFxxZRjZyywqk25ovyzTfCkwHoEYWE2TiApEkf92pTcVn86YkFhDQCSJWboJu75NAEtDxkiJelUut3DmHp0Pu91U17cKC6JxUSIHlTQAxbNHhUfkx0YdE6sTvzK2lG/XJcZdA/Nx6qia9548EsBoi71vY1GlsSn7pEf5pg5yCJF5fAufD9hRSPI5OX2TKtj3hYXMr8UXQ6VaDBf4PiJjQ8MNg+q4cXtr+BpK1uHtxm0BuRHlcM4eBkTyuia93Xc88Ojwsma2tlCrwg==
VERIFIED  = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution with bouncy castle can look like this

```kotlin
@Test
fun signDigestAndMessageSHA256() {
    val message = "message"

    val digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256").digest(payload.toByteArray())
    val encodedDigest: ByteArray = DigestInfo(AlgorithmIdentifier(NISTObjectIdentifiers.id_sha256, DERNull.INSTANCE), digest).encoded

    var signature = Signature.getInstance("NONEwithRSA")
    signature.initSign(privateKey)
    signature.update(encodedDigest)
    val signedDigest = signature.sign()

    signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA")
    signature.initSign(privateKey)
    signature.update(payload.toByteArray())
    val signedMessage = signature.sign()

    Assert.assertEquals(signedDigest.joinToString(), signedMessage.joinToString())
}
```